# Hyper-V-VMConnect with Kerberos rather than NTLM?

Tags: ntlm

I am running Hyper-V for years. Recently I tried to harden my environment by applying GPOs that disable NTLM, as NTLM is discouraged by Microsoft. Now Hyper-V VMConnect stopped working and I keep getting “An authentication error has occurred. The function requested is not supported …
This could be due to CreSSP encryption oracle remediation. For more information, see
[https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866660”](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866660%E2%80%9D) if either client or server is running with NTLM disabled (I applied the GPO selectively for testing).

The GPOs I used are
[image]

Did anyone succeed in disabling NTLM with Hyper-V-VMConnect? Which GPOs did you apply?
Just for the basics, file sharing, RDP, Win-RM are working with NTLM disabled, at least as far as I tested. I am running a Samba AD.

Comment: Since this is more about the configuration of Hyper-V and not information security, I believe [sf] will be able to provide better answers. I'm voting to migrate the question to there.

Comment: It is definitely about security (or lack thereof). I doubt a typcial Hyper-V user will be able to answer. I am hoping for someone whose company tried to disable NTLM like me and then experienced the same and found a solution to it, or did not expericence the same and can probably spot the difference to their configuration.

Comment: No, you are not asking about whether or not NTLM is secure for a given purpose in a given scenario, nor are you asking anything else *about* security. You ask how to configure software to make it do what you want to do.